# Web Site Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

Tags: visual-studio, web-services, linq-to-sql

just started to use web services of Visual Studio
on my data base my user_id value is nvarchar() I want to select it and serve as a method on my URL The mistak line is below inside my method. 
Would be very helpfull to have any solution. Thank you.

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetContant(string id)
{
    var json = "";
    var contact = from result in dc.mezura_users
          where result.user_id = Int32.Parse(id) // here is my mistake
                  select result;
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    json = jss.Serialize(contact);
    return json;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string GetContant(string id)
    {
        var json = "";
        var newid = Int32.Parse(id);
        var contact = from result in dc.mezura_users
              where result.user_id = newid // here is my mistake
                      select result;
        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        json = jss.Serialize(contact);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Since your user_id is nvarchar in db. You might need to use it like, where result.user_id = id. No need to convert it to int.

Comment: Thanks for attention, I have tried it, then i get 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'  error